# how to add class and slide toggle on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to do responsive design, on screen change I am displaying nav button and by clicking its removing the old class and adding new class it's not sliding down it's just showing too quick and I want to slide up on clicking again the nav button how do I do that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiXpd.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var screenSize = 0;

$('#responsiveBtn').on('click', function(){

    $('#topMenuDiv').removeClass('topMenu-no-resp').addClass('topMenu-  
    resp');
    $('#topMenuDiv ul').removeClass('topnav').addClass('topnav-resp');

});



$(window).resize(function() {
      screenSize = ($(window).width());

      if(screenSize > 1200){

    $('#topMenuDiv').removeClass('topMenu-resp').addClass('topMenu-no-
    resp');
    $('#topMenuDiv ul').removeClass('topnav-resp').addClass('topnav');

      }

});
```

Comment: are you trying to display and hide the 5 contents (culture blog videos events contactus) using the 3 bar button?

Comment: yes onclick display  and again on click hide

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.slideToggle();` function to toggle your menu. I think this [link](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) may help you.

```
$('#topMenuDiv').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows you to easily hide and show your elements by using the hide()/show() or toggle() functions.

```
$('#responsiveBtn').click(function() { 
    $("#topMenuDiv").toggle();
});
```

For more read look at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp